# Iteration and filtering of a Scala Map

Tags: scala

I have the following result Map that has the type `Map[Long,Map[String,String]]`. I would like to convert the Map to a `List[Seq[Long,String]]`.

The following code does this well:

```
val test = for((time, m) <- ret) yield for((k, v) <- m) yield Seq(time, v)
```

The issue is I actually only want to include the `Seq(time, v)` where `v` is unique. For example, currently I get the following values:

```
    [[
        1344969305196000,
        "Ry7H5_client"
    ],
    [
        1344969777610000,
        "Ry7H5_client"
    ],
    [
        1344965964890000,
        "SOCKET/f6KGcMSVi7"
    ],
    [
        1344969919131000,
        "Ry7H5_client"
    ]]
```

I would like to only include the "Ry7H5_client" once in my result set. What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: How do you determine which of the 3 "Ry7H5_client" in your example to include? Should it just be the first instance?

Comment: yeah first would be fine

Comment: Note that "first" doesn't really mean anything here (unless you sort by the time or whatever), since maps don't have a defined iteration order.

Comment: What do you mean by List[Seq[Long,String]]?  This isn't valid.  Currently your function returns Iterable[Iterable[Seq[Any]]] (concretely, List[List[List[Any]]]).  Do you really mean List[Seq[(Long,String)]] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the keys to delete with sth like

```
val res = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1)

val keysToDelete = res.groupBy(_._2).collect { case (_, m) if m.size > 1 => m.keys }.flatten
// keysToDelete: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(1, 3)

val resultMap = res -- keysToDelete
// resultMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(4 -> 1)
```

edit:

to collect the keys for all values, that contain a phrase you can do

```
Map(1 -> "FOO_SOCKET_BAR", 2 -> "FOO_BAR").collect { case (key,value) if value.contains("SOCKET") => key }
```

and to be more efficient, you could also use a compiled regex here:

```
val regex = ".*SOCKET.*".r
Map(1 -> "FOO_SOCKET_BAR", 2 -> "FOO_BAR").collect { case (key,regex()) => key }
```

Comment: Thats cool.  One other question what if I wanted to remove the values that contained a specific word.  Say for my example I don't want to include the entry with the value that contains "SOCKET"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple generators in your for-comprehension (if might be used as well):

```
val test = (for {
  (time, m) <- ret
  (k,v) <- m
  if v == "Ry7H5_client"
} yield Seq(time, v)).toList
```

Comment: Yes I tried that, the issue with that is it then returns an empty array which breaks the returns signature type

Comment: Ok, than you can surround the expression with parthese and call toList at the end. I edited this.

Answer (score 0):

Just groupBy the Strings and then map to the head of each group:

```
scala> val list = List((1344969305196000L, "Ry7H5_client"), (1344969777610000L,  
"Ry7H5_client"), (1344965964890000L,"SOCKET/f6KGcMSVi7"), (1344969919131000L, "R 
y7H5_client"))
list: List[(Long, java.lang.String)] = List((1344969305196000,Ry7H5_client), 
(1344969777610000,Ry7H5_client), (1344965964890000,SOCKET/f6KGcMSVi7), 
(1344969919131000,Ry7H5_client))

scala> list.groupBy(x => x._2).map((e) =>  e._2.head).toList
res0: List[(Long, java.lang.String)] = List((1344965964890000,SOCKET/f6KGcMSVi7),
(1344969305196000,Ry7H5_client))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
object SO extends App {

  val ret = Map(
    1344969305196000L -> Map("a" -> "Ry7H5_client"),
    1344969777610000L -> Map("a" -> "Ry7H5_client"),
    1344965964890000L -> Map("a" -> "SOCKET/f6KGcMSVi7"),
    1344969919131000L -> Map("a" -> "Ry7H5_client"))

  val test2 = for {
    (m, time) <- ret.map(_.swap)
    (k, v) <- m
  } yield Seq(time, v)

  println(test2)
}
```

Gives List(List(1344969919131000, Ry7H5_client), List(1344965964890000, SOCKET/f6KGcMSVi7))

ps. the "a" in the Map is just to make the types match your original problem, it looks like its not important.